# Compute $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x^a)-f(x)}{x}$

Tags: calculus, limits

> Let $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be a function differentiable at $0$. Compute the limit $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x^a)-f(x)}{x}$$ for all fixed $a \geq1$.

I have no idea about this limit because it seems that L'Hopital does not work on it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: What's wrong with l'Hopital? Why doesn't it work?

Comment: @Arthur because f is only differentiable at one point,and I see the defination on Rudin. It says that f must be differentiable in (a,b). It is my hesitation. Thank~

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For  $a>1$

$$\frac{f(x^a)-f(x)}{x}=\frac{f(x^a)-f(0)+f(0)-f(x)}{x}=\frac{f(x^a)-f(0)}{x-0}-\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}\\\to a0^{a-1}f'(0^a)-f'(0)=-f'(0)$$

For  $a=1$
$$\frac{f(x^a)-f(x)}{x}=0$$

Comment: Good answer. This doesn't need l'Hopital

Comment: @Math_QED Thanks! I always try to avoid l'Hopital!

Comment: It is very clear! Thanks you a lots!

Comment: That first limit after split via subtraction does not need chain rule and derivatives as you seem to do. Just multiply numerator denominator by $x^{a-1}$ and one see that it tends to $0\cdot f'(0)$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh you are absolutly right, do you think I should change the answer or the solution is correct also by chain rule?

Comment: No  need. I just gave an alternative. +1 was given already.

Comment: @ParamanandSinghThnaks for the hint!